# DebugBreak in Unix/ Linux?

Tags: unix, debugbreak

Do we have similar windows API of DebugBreak in Unix/ Linux. I want to debug a daemon process which should open NetBeans when DebugBreak statement is executed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whav! this is what I am looking for Embedded break points in C http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.in/2012/01/embedding-gdb-breakpoints-in-c-source.html and to get sample program have a look in to https://github.com/kmcallister/embedded-breakpoints

Answer (score 9):

there is `__builtin_trap()` GCC intrinsic.

Comment: Whav! this is what I am looking for http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.in/2012/01/embedding-gdb-breakpoints-in-c-source.html and to get sample program have a look in to https://github.com/kmcallister/embedded-breakpoints

Comment: This causes SIGILL (illegal instruction) when hit, and subsequently kills the program. At least for me. Using `raise(SIGTRAP)` works.